# jQuery Validation plugin not accepting float value started with .(dot)

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am looking for help regarding to [jquery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/).  I am using number option to accept only numbers like bellow

```
$("#myform").validate({ rules: { field: { required: true, number: true } } });
```

it allows 1, 0.9, 1.5 and etc. which is good but it doesn't allow **.9** .How can i make it accept even its started with dot.

There is [example](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/number)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you found the answer?

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you'll likely have to change the source of the plugin. Why don't you simply ensure that the form data is in the proper format? Bind a function to the `blur` event for input fields which appends a preceding 0 to the value, if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for reply.How can i make sure  preceding 0.i'm not good with regular expressions.please help me!